# Zip file automation with bash/git

Tags: python, bash, automation

I have a directory like `/home/folder1/folder2/index.html`

In the end I have to give the files that have changes and zip it. So I have to create a folder name 2016/11/8 and the content is `home/folder1/folder2/css/style.css`

if says I changed the style. It's tedious but I couldn't find a way to automate this.

Comment: your top item is a file. And I assume you are talking about files that have changes compared to their server copy, right? and are you looking for files with local changes, server changes or both?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to get the files that have difference between 2 coimmitss,

```
git archive --format=zip HEAD `git diff --name-only <SHA> HEAD` > difference.zip
```

Following will give you the difference between current and given SHA

```
git diff --name-only <SHA> HEAD
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: can git zip stuff?